# ng-if, not equal to?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch, angular-ng-if

I have a simple ng-reapt that displays a list of values.. On some of the outputs, i have a couple of ng-if to show/hide DIVs.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="details in myDataSet">

    <p>{{ details.Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ details.DOB  }}</p>

       <div ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status == '0'">
           <p>No payment</p>
       </div>

       <div ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status == '1' || details.Payment[0].Status == '2'">
           <p>Late</p>
       </div>

       <div ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status == '3' || details.Payment[0].Status == '4' || details.Payment[0].Status == '5'">
           <p>Some payment made</p>
       </div>

       <div ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status == '6'">
           <p>Late and further taken out</p>
       </div>

       <div ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status != '0' || details.Payment[0].Status != '1' || details.Payment[0].Status != '2' || details.Payment[0].Status != '3' || details.Payment[0].Status != '4' || details.Payment[0].Status != '5' || details.Payment[0].Status != '6'">
           <p>Error</p>
       </div>

    <p>{{ details.Gender}}</p>

</div>
```

My application is displaying an error when attempting to display the `!=` section.

Comment: Why would i get down voted for this?

Comment: My guess: there's no mention of what the error is and there is no description of what you have tried to do to solve it.

Answer (score 13):

It is better to use ng-switch

```
<div ng-switch on="details.Payment[0].Status">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <!-- code to render a large video block-->
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
        <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used ng-switch originally, but ng-switch does not cater to multiple expressions in a signle switch ie ng-switch-when="1" || =2

Answer (score 12):

Here is a nifty solution with a filter:

```
app.filter('status', function() {

  var statusDict = {
    0: "No payment",
    1: "Late",
    2: "Late",
    3: "Some payment made",
    4: "Some payment made",
    5: "Some payment made",
    6: "Late and further taken out"
  };

  return function(status) {
    return statusDict[status] || 'Error';
  };
});
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="details in myDataSet">
  <p>{{ details.Name }}</p>
  <p>{{ details.DOB  }}</p>
  <p>{{ details.Payment[0].Status | status }}</p>
  <p>{{ details.Gender}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: right now called Custom Pipe with Angular 4: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Answer (score 3):

That's all unnecessary logic in partials, reduce it to something like this and process your data in controller/service where it should be

```
<div ng-repeat="details in myDataSet">

    <p>{{ details.Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ details.DOB  }}</p>
    <p>{{details.Payment[0].StatusName}}</p>
    <p>{{ details.Gender}}</p>

</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.forEach(myDataSet.Payment, function (payment) {
  if(payment.Status === 0){
    payment.StatusName = 'No Payment';
  } else if(payment.Status === 1 || payment.Status === 2){
    payment.StatusName = 'Late';
  } else if(payment.Status === 3 || payment.Status === 4 || payment.Status === 5){
    payment.StatusName = 'Some payment made';
  } else if(payment.Status === 6){
    payment.StatusName = 'Late and further taken out';
  }else{
    payment.StatusName = 'Error';
  }
})
```

Comment: While I agree with your statement about logic sometimes you want it to live in the template so that you can conditionally load certain markup.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status != '6'".
```

Sorry about that, but I think you can use ng-show or ng-hide.

Comment: @AlguMS - Thanks, however i dont understand how this will achieve what i have asked.

Answer (score 3):

Try below solution

```
ng-if="details.Payment[0].Status != '0'"

Use below condition(! prefix with true condition) instead of above

ng-if="!details.Payment[0].Status == '0'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like "hacks" but in a quick pinch for a deadline I have done this

```
<li ng-if="edit === false && filtered.length === 0">
    <p ng-if="group.title != 'Dispatcher News'" style="padding: 5px">No links in group.</p>
</li>
```

Yes, I have another inner nested ng-if, I just didn't like too many conditions on one line.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty good solutions here but they don't help to understand why the problem actually happens.

But it's very simple, you just need to understand how logic OR `||` works. Whole expression will evaluate to `true` when either of its sides evaluates to `true`.

Now let's look at your case. Assume whole `details.Payment[0].Status` is `Status` and it's a number for brevity. Then we have `Status != 0 || Status != 1 || ...`.

Imagine `Status = 1`:

```
( 1 != 0 || 1 != 1 || ... ) =
(  true  || false  || ... ) =
(       true       || ... ) = ... = true
```

Now imagine `Status = 0`:

```
( 0 != 0 || 0 != 1 || ... ) =
( false  ||  true  || ... ) =
(       true       || ... ) = ... = true
```

As you it doesn't even matter what you have as `...` as logical `OR` of first two expressions gives you `true` which will be the result of the full expression.

What you actually need is logical `AND` `&&` that will be true only if **both** its sides are `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible as of AngularJS 1.5.10, using `ng-switch-when-separator`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myDataSet = [{Name: 'Michelle', Gender: 'Female', DOB: '01/12/1986', Payment: [{Status: '0'}]},{Name: 'Steve', Gender: 'Male', DOB: '11/12/1982', Payment: [{Status: '1'}]},{Name: 'Dan', Gender: 'Male', DOB: '03/22/1976', Payment: [{Status: '2'}]},{Name: 'Doug', Gender: 'Male', DOB: '02/02/1980', Payment: [{Status: '3'}]},{Name: 'Mary', Gender: 'Female', DOB: '04/02/1976', Payment: [{Status: '4'}]},{Name: 'Cheyenne', Gender: 'Female', DOB: '07/10/1981', Payment: [{Status: '5'}]},{Name: 'Bob', Gender: 'Male', DOB: '02/16/1990', Payment: [{Status: '6'}]},{Name: 'Bad data', Gender: 'Blank', DOB: '01/01/1970', Payment: [{Status: '7'}]}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="details in myDataSet" ng-switch on="details.Payment[0].Status">

        <p>{{ details.Name }}</p>
        <p>{{ details.DOB  }}</p>

        <div ng-switch-when="0">
            <p>No payment</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="1|2" ng-switch-when-separator="|">
            <p>Late</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="3|4|5" ng-switch-when-separator="|">
            <p>Some payment made</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="6">
            <p>Late and further taken out</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-default>
            <p>Error</p>
        </div>
        
        <p>{{ details.Gender}}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```